# Incorrect result of dividing the product of two integers by their gcd

Tags: python-3.x, casting, integer-division

We know that for two numbers 'a' and 'b'; product of a & b is equal to the product of GCD(a,b) and LCM (a,b).

So in order to find the LCM of two numbers I wrote this algorithm in Python:

```
def gcd(a,b):

  if b==0:
     return a
  else:
     a_rem = a%b
     return gcd(b,a_rem)

print(int(a*b/(gcd(a,b)))
```

Now while checking for different test cases I found out this:

Input:
226553150 1023473145

My output:
46374212988031352

Correct output:
46374212988031350

I'm unable to find out why this is happening, only the last digit is wrong for some reason !!

Comment: those numbers are outside safe integer limits for float, yes. So rather than converting back from float, stick with int the whole time

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using Python3. The division '/' does float number calculation and returns result as a float, which is not precise for large number. This doesn't relate to you gcd function. You will loose more digits of precision if you do division with even larger numbers. Try int(12345678923456789123456789 / 1)

Comment: Is there any way to avoid that error in computations for larger numbers?

Comment: @AnupamKhandelwal You should use integer division '\\' instead of '\' whenever only integer values concern.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, this is the output at every step of GCD

1023473145 226553150 
226553150 117260545 
117260545 109292605 
109292605 7967940 
7967940 5709385 
5709385 2258555 
2258555 1192275 
1192275 1066280 
1066280 125995 
125995 58320 
58320 9355 
9355 2190 
2190 595 
595 405 
405 190 
190 25 
25 15 
15 10 
10 5 
5 0

which gives GCD as 5, which is used for division of a * b and essentially converting float to int as a result the difference.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the loss of precision due to integer-to-float conversion, use integer division `//` instead of float division `/`:

```
print(a*b//gcd(a,b))  # prints 46374212988031350
```

A slight optimization: since each of a and b is divisibe by their gcd, divide before multiplying, so the size of integers is smaller.

```
print(a*(b//gcd(a,b)))  # prints 46374212988031350
```

Further optimization: in Python 3.5+ [gcd is built in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gcd) so use `from math import gcd` instead of implementing it yourself.